# Looking for MySQL alternative primary key "auto increment" for temporal information table for insert query

Tags: mysql, insert, auto-increment

I have a table where I enter many temporal items every day.

It sometimes can get nasty and the primary key get to up to 10k increments.

Since most of the time the temporal items are deleted, I don't see a reason to keep the primary key at such a high number.

What I am looking for is a way to create a query where the next inserted row key number will be the next available minimum ID.

**I know how to do it with server side code.**

Comment: Even with gaps of 10k, using a `BIGINT UNSIGNED` type one could still store almost 2 quadrillion records... so the first question is: *does it matter?*  The second question is, if there really is some valid reason for avoiding "gaps", why not make a `TIMESTAMP` type field your PK (or `TIMESTAMP(6)` in MYSQL >= 5.6.4 if you want microsecond accuracy)?  If there is some valid reason for avoiding both "gaps" and a `TIMESTAMP` PK, why is it that you're deleting so many records?  Perhaps you can change the architecture so that records are only inserted into your table when you require permanence?

Comment: The records I am saving are temporary. They are "transferred" into the  constant record table if certain aspects are met. 
I won't use BIGINT nor TIMESTAMP because it requires more space and reduce the overall performance. Therefore I would like to keep it in small number, with small capacity and faster search results.

Comment: You seem to be conflating a number of issues: "space" and "performance" are usually negatively correlated (the more space one consumes to store preprocessed results, e.g. an index tree, the faster that read operations will be); besides which, `TIMESTAMP` requires 4 bytes of storage - the same as `INT`.  Also, nominal value is irrelevant to the storage space consumed by an integer (albeit that `BIGINT` does indeed use more storage than `INT`, but the CPU word size and data bus width in all modern computers is 64-bits and therefore the only real difference lies in disk storage and IO).

Comment: And in any event, why not merely generate the PK in the constant record table and avoid this problem altogether?

Comment: You arguments are valid in case I want to INT and if I am using a 64-bit OS. Which is not the case.

I'll try to describe the situation to you: People send msges to eachother (for example whatsapp) and you want to store the msges in a temporary table until the user who was supposed to receive those msges got online and got it, then you either delete the temporary record or transfer it to the constant table.
Thing is most msges are temporary for only a few second, and there could be many msges being sent at the same time to the server, therefore I want to reduce the threshold as much as I can.

Comment: I do not want to use xmpp protocol. 
I also want to try counter future DDOS attacks by making the queries as fast as possible.

Answer (score 0):

1) It is possible to find the smallest unused id but I'm not sure that would qualify as fast, e.g., (another option is to join with an existing table)

```
set @rowid = 0;
SELECT rowid FROM
(select @rowid := @rowid + 1 as rowid 
from TABLE) rowids
left join TABLE ON (rowid = ID)
WHERE ID is null
ORDER BY rowid limit 1;
```

2) You could also maintain a table of free available ids.

3) Also, instead of deleting records, you could flag them as "deleted" and then just reuse the records.

Comment: 1) How?
2) Too consuming.
3) SELECT may need to go through all the table at worst case.

Comment: I've added an example. Using an existing table for joining is a better option, if available. I don't see a big problem with 3) if you use an index, and indeed flag delete instead of real delete should be more efficient (it is a technique used in FAT).

Comment: You're actually very right!

I've ran some performance tests and apparently not only that tinyint doesn't really bother my space wise.. It also saves me the time of deleting a row and creating a new one.

I'm just updating the first "deleted" and it is almost 10% faster.

Comment: lovely! thks for the feedback